# Yii2 only display data where posted on date is less than or equal to current datetime

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a field within my database called publish_on_date where I store the date the post should become active.

Now I am unsure on how to add the query to my dataprovider/search model.

So I need to add a query that will query the display date and check if it is less than or equal to now (now being the current date/server date).

Here is my current search functon

```
    public function search($params, $pageSize = 3, $published = false)
{
    $query = Article::find();

    // this means that editor is trying to see articles
    // we will allow him to see published ones and drafts made by him
    if ($published === true) 
    {
        $query->where(['status' => Article::STATUS_PUBLISHED]);
        $query->orWhere(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id]);
    }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['id' => SORT_DESC]],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => $pageSize,
        ]
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
        'status' => $this->status,
        'category' => $this->category,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'summary', $this->summary])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'content', $this->content]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add someplace another condition with

```
$query->andWhere('publish_on_date <= NOW()');
```

You can add this when you first create the query

```
$query = Article::find()->andWhere('publish_on_date <= NOW()');
```

or later down the page